# Force Apache to change http headers from Weblogic

Tags: apache, http-headers, weblogic

I've configured an Apache in front of a Weblogic. Everything, including static content is stored on Weblogic.

That Apache is configured to set Cache-control max-age and an expiration date HTTP headers of static content when the response comes from Weblogic.

Everything seems to work fine when a user makes the first request of a static content and Weblogic replies with a 200 OK but, once the expiration date is over and browser makes a conditional request, Weblogic replies with a 304 Not Modified BUT that response is not overriden by Apache config so a Cache-Control: max-age=0 arrives to the browser and no new expiration date comes to the browser.

I've seend that I'm unable to set a config to the default weblogic.servlet.FileServlet and, due some development issues, it's impossible to set a custom made Servlet that overrides the default one.

The only option then, is to force Apahe to update the headers of a 304 response from Weblogic.

How can this been achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the configuration of Apache. I had configured the rules related with cache expiration http headers given a mime-type. On a 304 response from Weblogic there is no mime because there is no data so I've updated the rules to take into account the extension of the file types instead mimes and now is working properly